# Scaffolding - Database first approach for image data type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

To quickly present some ideas , I generally use scaffolding with database first approach. Even though I prefer to store only image path in the database, recently, I came across a situation where I had to store images in SQL database ,and could not find scaffolding useful at all for image data type. Am I missing something? How can I use image data type like other primitive data types with scaffolding ?

Comment: Consider using binary datatype in SQL Server such as `blob`, `varbinary` or `image`.

Comment: @Alexander, does those data types work for you when you create a scaffolding project ?

Comment: It will be mapped to `byte[]`.